# access the former value of an attribute in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Lets say I have a model (an ActiveRecord class):

```
class Sample < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :x1
end
```

I know that

```
Sample.last.x1 == 1 #true
```

If I set `Sample.last.x1 = 3` then `Sample.last.x1_was == 1 #true`.

But when I set the value of x1 again: `Sample.last.x1 = 8` then `Sample.last.x1_was == 3 #false`, but `Sample.last.x1 == 1 #true`

I can guess why it happens (Sample.last wasn't saved since the change), but I want to find a way to retrieve the former value (not the db value) of x1. Can you suggest a way to do it?

Comment: 1) it couldn't work with attr_accessor, only with actual columns 2) store an object, you're redoing a query each time, resetting the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a reason to do that, but if you really need to, you could override the setter to store the various changes as you go.

```
def x1=( value )
  @previous_x1_value = x1
  super
end

def previous_x1_value
  @previous_x1_value || x1_was
end
```

Answer (score 0):

IT's all built in to rails. See the documentation for `[ActiveRecord@dirty][1]`

```
  person.name = 'Bob'
  person.changed?       # => true
  person.name_changed?  # => true
  person.name_was       # => 'uncle bob'
  person.name_change    # => ['uncle bob', 'Bob']
  person.name = 'Bill'
  person.name_change    # => ['uncle bob', 'Bill']
```